# jQuery nested clone loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a beginner in jQuery. I don't know about nested loops. I am stuck on the first loop.

I have two issues.

I explained my questions in below screenshots.

```
   $( document ).ready(function() {

        var current_id = 0;
        $('#btn').click(function(){
            if(current_id < 4)
                nextElement($('#Outer_00'));
        })

        function nextElement(element){
            var newElement = element.clone();
            var id = current_id+1;
            current_id = id;
            if(id <10)id = "0"+id;
            newElement.attr("id",element.attr("id").split("_")[0]+"_"+id);
            var field = $('select', newElement).attr("id");
            $('select', newElement).attr("id", field.split("_")[0]+"_"+id );
            newElement.appendTo($("#elements"));
        }

    });



<div id="elements">
<button id="btn">Add</button>
    <div id="Outer_00" class="boxbg">
    <input type="text" name="" placeholder="text">
    <select id="Field1_00"><option>element1</option><option>Next level</option></select>


    </div>
</div>
```

[image: screenshot1]

[image: screenshot2]

Answer (score 0):

This may help..

For the first problem, use hide and show functions of jquery and try giving them different id's.

For the second problem, declare a global variable and use the onclick function for that add button and increment the global variable for each click and then add the div tags or do whatever has to be done. After the global variable has reached a limit, disable or hide the add button.

I haven't tried it but this may help. Inform me if it worked.